# How can i pass a view reference from Object Animator OfObject(..) method animation?

Tags: android

I need to move circles along a circular path for that i am using Object Animator and Path evaluator.All the information is dynamic means it is changing when i receive response so that total number of circles can be changed at runtime.Here is the 1 part of method where all circles are positioning themselves according to their position on screen that is if user release the touch then this method gets called -:

```
public void slideDownSetToCenter() {

    for (int i = 0; i < leftCurrentRunningAnimation.length; i++) {

        Logger.i(TAG, "in slide down animation");
        if (leftReadyToMove[i]) {

            if (leftUpQueue.contains(i)) {
                leftUpQueue.remove(i);
            }
            leftAngle = leftSlice * ++leftAllCirclesAngles[i];
            Logger.i("circle leftAngle points of curve down", String.valueOf(leftAllCirclesAngles[i]));
            if (leftAngle > leftAngleTop) {
                if (i < leftCurrentRunningAnimation.length - 1) {
                    leftReadyToMove[i + 1] = true; // set next circle to
                                                    // move
                }
            }
            Arrays.fill(leftCurrentRunningAnimation, false);
            leftCurrentRunningAnimation[i] = true;

            Logger.i(TAG, "leftAngle" + leftAngle);

            if (leftReadyToMove[i] == true && leftAngle == leftAngleDownOut) {

                leftReadyToMove[i] = false;
                leftDownStack.add(i);
            }

            xPosition = (int) (leftCircleCenterX + leftCircleX * Math.cos(leftAngle));
            yPosition = (int) (leftCircleCenterY + leftCircleY * Math.sin(leftAngle));

            Path = new AnimatorPath();
            Path.moveTo(xPosition, yPosition);
            Path.lineTo(xPosition, yPosition);
            while (true) {
                if (leftAngle == leftAngleDownOut) {
                    break;
                }

                leftAngle = leftSlice * ++leftAllCirclesAngles[i];
                xPosition = (int) (leftCircleCenterX + leftCircleX * Math.cos(leftAngle));
                yPosition = (int) (leftCircleCenterY + leftCircleY * Math.sin(leftAngle));
                Path.lineTo(xPosition, yPosition);
                Logger.i(TAG, "path.........");
            }
            slideCircleAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(DynamicCircleSwipeAnimation.this, "leftButtonLocationDynamic", new PathEvaluator(), Path.getPoints().toArray());
            slideCircleAnimator.setInterpolator(linearInterpolator);
            slideCircleAnimator.setDuration(500);
            context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    slideCircleAnimator.start();
                }
            });

        }
        break;
    }
}
```

Here is the Object animator's animation method -:

```
  public void setLeftButtonLocationDynamic(final PathPoint newLoc) {

    for (int i = 0; i < leftCurrentRunningAnimation.length; i++) {
        if (leftCurrentRunningAnimation[i] == true) {
            Logger.i("current button id", String.valueOf(i));
            leftArrayOfButtons[i].setTranslationX(newLoc.mX);
            leftArrayOfButtons[i].setTranslationY(newLoc.mY);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here my animation is not happening in correct way that' why i need to pass my view reference from Object.OfObject() method so that i can get it in setLeftButtonLocationDynamic(final PathPoint newLoc,View v).Is anyone has any idea how can i do this?I searched a lot and tried to develop custom class of ObjectAnimator,ValueAnimator and ProperyViewHolder classes but when i copied it from google open source then i get errors in that.Any help is appreciable?

Comment: just create a custom Animarion, it will take more or less ten lines of code

Comment: @pskink Can you share any similar example?

Comment: just extend Animation class and override applyTransformation method

Comment: Object animator is used for such things only.Why should i extend and make it custom as object animator is providing me such functionality for that?

Comment: why? because as i said you can move Views along a circular path in just ten lines of code, now compare it with your code...

Comment: Your question is easy, yet no one understood it and that is why you did not get answers. Fix it and be clearer, make it more compact do not just put code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here to achieve this i changed the approach to move all circles.Previously, i was using ObjectAnimator to move circles one by one and now i am using Animator set for x position and y position.I play both animation together.

Here is the example -:

```
public void SlideDownFromRightAnimation() {

    int rightArrayOfButtonsLength = rightArrayOfButtons.length;

    Logger.i(TAG, "queue " + rightUpQueue.size() + "= stack " + rightDownStack.size());
    if (rightUpQueue.size() == rtNumberOfButtons) {
        Arrays.fill(rightReadyToMove, false);
        rightReadyToMove[0] = true;
        rightUpQueue.poll();
    } else if (rightDownStack.size() == rtNumberOfButtons) {
        rightUpQueue.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < rightArrayOfButtonsLength; i++) {
            rightUpQueue.add(rightDownStack.pop());
            rightAllCirclesAngles[i] = rightCircleUpOutPosition;
        }
        Arrays.fill(rightReadyToMove, false);
        rightReadyToMove[0] = true;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rightArrayOfButtonsLength; i++) {

        Logger.i(TAG, "in slide down animation");
        if (rightReadyToMove[i]) {

            if (rightUpQueue.contains(rightArrayOfButtons[i].getTag())) {
                rightUpQueue.remove(i);
            }
            rightAngle = rightSlice * --rightAllCirclesAngles[i];
            Logger.i("circle rightAngle points of curve down", String.valueOf(rightAllCirclesAngles[i]));
            if (rightAngle <= rightAngleTop) {
                if (i < rightArrayOfButtonsLength - 1) {
                    rightReadyToMove[i + 1] = true; // set next circle to
                                                    // move
                }
            }

            Logger.i(TAG, "rightAngle" + rightAngle);

            if (rightAngle <= rightAngleDownOut) {

                rightReadyToMove[i] = false;
                rightDownStack.add((Integer)rightArrayOfButtons[i].getTag());
                rightAllCirclesAngles[i] = rightCircleDownOutPosition;
                rightStartAnimation(rightAngle, null, i);
            } else {
                double rightAngleNext = rightSlice * rightAllCirclesAngles[i];

                if (rightAngleNext <= rightAngleDownOut) {

                    rightReadyToMove[i] = false;
                    rightDownStack.add((Integer)rightArrayOfButtons[i].getTag());
                }

                rightStartAnimation(rightAngle, rightAngleNext, i);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

and here is the right wheels animation function -:

```
public void rightStartAnimation(Double rightAngle, Double rightAngleNext, int bttnId) {
    xPosition = (int) (rightCircleCenterX + rightCircleX * Math.cos(rightAngle));
    yPosition = (int) (rightCircleCenterY + rightCircleY * Math.sin(rightAngle));

    if (rightAngleNext != null) {
        xPosition = (int) (rightCircleCenterX + rightCircleX * Math.cos(rightAngleNext));
        yPosition = (int) (rightCircleCenterY + rightCircleY * Math.sin(rightAngleNext));
    }

    final ObjectAnimator animation1 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rightArrayOfButtons[bttnId], "x", rightArrayOfButtons[bttnId].getX(), xPosition);
    animation1.setDuration(0);
    animation1.setInterpolator(linearInterpolator);
    final ObjectAnimator animation2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(rightArrayOfButtons[bttnId], "y", rightArrayOfButtons[bttnId].getY(), yPosition);
    animation2.setDuration(0);
    animation2.setInterpolator(linearInterpolator);
    final AnimatorSet set = new AnimatorSet();
    set.setInterpolator(linearInterpolator);
    context.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            set.playTogether(animation1, animation2);
            set.start();
        }
    });
}
```